# Unexpected results reading and writing large array with bin file from MATLAB to C

Tags: c, arrays, matlab

I'm having trouble reading a large array in C with the .bin format that has been created in MATLAB. Below is my code. I've tested it for the simple array of [1, 2; 3, 4] and it works fine. But for my intended matrix of size 256 x 256 with small values, I get unexpected results.

```
  FILE * fileptr;
  double * buffer;
  int num_read;

  fileptr = fopen("matrix.bin", "rb");

  if (fileptr == NULL)
   {
     printf("couldn't read file\n");
   }
  else
   {
     buffer = malloc(sizeof(double) * 256 * 256);
     check_mem(buffer);

     num_read = fread(buffer, sizeof(double), 256 * 256, fileptr);
     fclose(fileptr);

     printf("num read: %d\n", num_read);
     printf("buffer: %.16f\n", buffer[0]);
   }


---------------------------------------------------------------------
output:
num read: 65536
buffer = 0.0000000000016900;
```

In MATLAB the matrix is normally filled with numbers ranging from 1.4e-5 to 1.6e-5. But I tested it with a matrix of the same size filled with 1's and I get the same result. For some reason I'm able to index into the buffer array with an index > 65535 (256*256), after which there are some garbage values. So perhaps there is some memory alignment issue going on.

In MATLAB I do the following commands to write to the bin file.

```
fid = fopen('matrix.bin', 'wb');
fwrite(fid, matrix, 'double');
fclose(fid);
```

I'm writing the file on Windows running MATLAB (little-endian) and the C code on Ubuntu (also little-endian). I've forced MATLAB to write the bin file in little endian just in case but it didn't help either.

Comment: Do not use magic numbers. You already have `256` four times here. A single `#define` would make your code more readable (or two, if you do not necessarily need a square matrix). And using an index out-of-range invokes undefined behaviour. C does not check the index (it actually cannot, because `buffer` is just a pointer, not an array.

Comment: "For some reason I'm able to index into the buffer array with an index > 65535 (256*256), after which there are some garbage values. So perhaps there is some memory alignment issue going on." Nothing to do with alignment, everything to do with accessing out-of-bounds and invoking undefined behaviour. Get [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Use it. Or enjoy the demons issuing forth from your nostrils.

Comment: @IskarJarak: Small correction: `256 * 256 ` is `65536`, you are off by one, likely meaning the max. index.

Comment: @Olaf That was a direct copy and paste from the question... I would switch it to italics but the edit window just closed.

Comment: You've shown the output but what exactly is the input value? That is, what is the expected output for that first double value that is printed out. So it's really not clear what you mean by "unexpected results".

Comment: The code shown seems ok. But you do not show all of it, neither the file-format, nor the actual function, or what exactly you are doing. If you are complaining the program does not warn for out-of-bounds index: do not use C! Otherwise provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IskarJarak: Ok, sorry, just read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've managed to fix the problem. There are some issues in the way MATLAB opens or writes data to existing binary files. I didn't think using the same name for the binary file would make a difference, but it works every time I change the name to something new. The documentation for fopen and fwrite specifically state that existing files are overwritten. However the problem still occurs even if I delete the file itself, so perhaps the name isn't flushing properly from a buffer somewhere. I'm now checking every bin file with a HEX editor in Ubuntu, Bless, to verify that the right matrix was copied which should prevent the problem in the future. Thanks all for the help.